# CountDown Timer value to be stored in shared preference

Tags: android, timer, sharedpreferences, countdown

Sorry if i didn't write a suitable title for my problem.
I am developing an android game in which i had to start count down timer from 10 minutes. The value to be stored in textView
Now my textView is showing the countdown value i.e it starts from 09:59 and decreasing second by second but obviously when i close the application and then restart its gone. This should be saved via shared preference but Iam confused how to used shared preference in it.
i.e. if i close the app when 07:45 minutes left and preference is saved then when i will return and restart the app after 2 minutes then it should show 05:45 minutes left then how can i get that? because if I subtract the countdown time from system time then it may be not the result that i wanted because system time is in hour format and iam using minute and second only.

Here is the code before oncreate

```
MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(600000,1000);
private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d";
```

and this is what iam using to get the countdown timer in textview

```
public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{

        public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            datetime.setText("Timer Completed,Now you can play");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            datetime.setText(""+String.format(FORMAT,

TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

        }
    }
```

Any link to specific code and shared preference example using countdown will help me a lot

Comment: Save the remaining number of seconds and when you calculated it. That should solve both of your requirements.

Comment: Just use the `AlarmManager` more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), `AlarmManager` will keep running, even when your application is closed.

Comment: You can save a timestamp at closing your app. On restart you calc the elapsed time with another timestamp.

Comment: Save the ramaining seconds and a timestamp in your shared preference. On restart you create another timestamp. With both timestamps you calc the elapsed time. Now load the remaining seconds from the shared pref and substract the elapsed time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create** an alarm set method, this is used to set/start alarm.

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context){ 
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TenMinuteTimer.class);   
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),10*60*1000, pendingIntent);  
}
```

**Cancel** the alarm, this method is used to remove the alarm once it has been reached

```
public void CancelAlarm(Context context){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TenMinuteTimer.class);   
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

**Save**  when the alarm completed those 10 minutes:

```
public class TenMinuteTimer extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Save, timer has completed.
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("timerCompleted", true).commit();

    //cancel the Alarm, no need for repeating (right?)
    CancelAlarm(this);
}
```

**Add** to your Manifest.XML:

```
 <receiver 
     android:name=".TenMinuteTimer"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:process=":remote"> 
 </receiver>
```

**Start/Set** your alarm whenever you want, by calling the `SetAlarm(this)` method

**Check** , when a user starts your application again just check if timer has completed by adding to your `onCreate()` :

```
Boolean usetTimerCompleted = prefs.getBoolean("timerCompleted", false);  //False if not yet saved (first time), or timer is not yet completed

if (usetTimerCompleted){
// User Timer is completed, now do something
}
```

This should work, 
If I did something wrong, please edit my post, or comment below.

**I didn't test this out!**

Comment: Ok sir lemme try this one

Comment: Ok, I editted my answer a litte bit, cause u might want to cancel the repeating alarm, so I added the code for that.